# Spring SecurityContextHolder getPrincipal model.User vs. userDetails.User

Tags: spring, testing, spring-security, runtime

During runtime, when i retrieve autheticated user like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

I get `User` from the model of my application:

> test.package.model.User

When i retrieve user during testing, i get user from `UserDetails`:

> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

I'am testing my beans with MockMvc as autheticated User.
During the test, i'am using InMemoryUserDetailsManager:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Collection<UserDetails> users = Collections.emptyList();

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        /** User from application model, not userDetails.User type */
        User user = new User("bob")
        users = Arrays.asList(user);
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
        return inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    }

    public Collection<UserDetails> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
```

And my Request during the test looks like this:

```
@WithUserDetails("bob") 
public void showUser() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user"))
                .andDo(print());
}
```

I would like to keep it consistent during runtime and testtime.
Which User-Type should i work with?  And why?

Answer (score 0):

without sending a request to you application you have the default context

so the user stocked in this context is an instance of

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

but when yo send a request to your application the context will change.